# How to program a simple music player?

Tags: c#

I've just completed a tutorial on C# language syntax from http://www.csharp-station.com/Tutorial.aspx
I'd like to get started programming a simple music player for practice. The music player should be able to index all the music files in a folder and be able to play them at random. Would someone point me to the right direction as to where I should start? Maybe a sample code from an opensource program? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some links for you to check out:

- http://www.csharphelp.com/archives4/archive680.html
- http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mgold/PoormansIPod01172007144720PM/PoormansIPod.aspx
- http://www.developerfusion.com/article/62/build-an-mp3-player/

Comment: Thank you, Dreas. Did you get those links from Google?

Comment: yup, Google's the first place I take a look at when I want to research about something

Comment: what was keyword did you use?